# Algebra with spectra: Vanishing in K(n) implies vanishing in a quotient of BP

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory, spectra

I'm having a confusion about doing algebra with spectra. My question occured while reading p. 10 of Sanath Devalapurkar's *Chromatic Homotopy Theory* where we are in the course of proving the thick subcategory theorem.

Let $R$ be a ring spectrum and suppose that the Hurewicz image of $x \in \pi_{\bullet}R$ inside $K(n)_{\bullet}R$ is zero for all $0 \leq n \leq \infty$. We define $$ P(n) = BP/(p, v_1, \cdots , v_{n-1}).$$ Sanath then claims that by assumption there is some finite $N$ for which $P(N) \wedge x^{-1} R$ is contractible.

I'm not too experienced with such computations yet, so I'm confused about how this follows.  It seems like that if one tries to translate this into ordinary algebra, then the $K(n)$-conditions amount to $x^{-1}R \otimes \mathbb{F}_p[v_n, v_n^{-1}] = 0$ (for an ordinary ring $R$ and $x \in R$) for all $n$ and the desired condition is $x^{-1}R \otimes \mathbb{F}_p[v_N^{-1}, v_N, v_{N+1}, v_{N+2}, \cdots] = 0$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

It sounds like one can already choose $N = 1$? Either I'm messing up the translation or I'm confused about ordinary algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me start by commenting on the algebraic analogue. I don't quite see why the desired condition in the algebraic analogue is $x^{-1}R\otimes \mathbb{F}_p[v_{N}^{-1}, v_N, v_{N+1}, v_{N+2},\ldots]=0$, and not only $x^{-1}R\otimes \mathbb{F}_p[v_N, v_{N+1}, v_{N+2},\ldots]=0$. The absence of this inversion of $v_{N}$ makes that you could not take $N=1$ and be done with it. Maybe this is where there is a mistake in you algebraic analogue?

The condition that we have to use to show that $P(N)\otimes x^{-1}R$ is contractible for some $N$ is the fact that the image of $x$ in $K(n)_*R$ is $0$ for $n=\infty$ specifically. To summarize the argument: we know that $K(\infty)\simeq \mathbb{F}_p\simeq P(\infty)$, which will give us that $P(\infty)\otimes x^{-1}R\simeq 0$. After that we use the analogue of the following algebraic fact: if $A$ is a commutative ring and $I=(a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ is an ideal of $A$, then if an element $x\in A$ is contained in $I$ it is also contained in some ideal $I_N=(a_1,\ldots,a_N)$, and as such, if the image of $x$ in $A/I$ is $0$, so is its image in $A/I_{N}$ for some finite $N$. In the case of spectra, this will precisely tell us that $P(N)\otimes x^{-1}R\simeq 0$ for some finite $N$.

Let us start being precise. For notational simplicity, I will assume that all elements $v_i$ and $x$ itself lie in degree $0$, because I will mess up degrees in the formulas otherwise. The argument in the general case is conceptually the same.

Let $A\in\mathrm{Sp}$ and suppose given elements $a_1,a_2,\ldots\in\pi_0(A)$. We can inductively define $A/(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ as cofiber of $-\cdot a_n\colon A/(a_1,\ldots a_{n-1})\to A/(a_1,\ldots a_{n-1})$. Define $I_n:\simeq\mathrm{fib}(A\to A/(a_1,\ldots,a_n))$. Of course, we want to think about $I_n$ as ''being the ideal $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$''. (Note that $A/I_n\simeq A/(a_1,\ldots a_n)$ holds by definition.) Let
$$
B:\simeq\mathrm{colim}(A\to A/I_1\to A/I_2\to\ldots)
$$
and put $I:\simeq\mathrm{fib}(A\to B)$. We want to think about $I$ as the ideal $(a_1,a_2,\ldots)$, and therefore want to show that $I\simeq\mathrm{colim}_n\,I_n$. For this, consider the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>{\mathrm{id}}>> A @>{\mathrm{id}}>>A @>{\mathrm{id}}>>\ldots\\
@VVV @VVV@VVV\\
A @>>>A/I_1@>>>A/I_2@>>>\ldots
\end{CD}
$$
We know that colimits commute with finite limits in $\mathrm{Sp}$ (this holds in any stable $\infty$-category, because finite products are finite coproducts, and pullback squares are also pushout squares), so if we take fibers of the vertical maps and then a sequential colimit (giving us $\mathrm{colim}_n\,I_n$), we get the same result as first taking sequential colimits and then a fiber (giving us $I$), and therefore $I\simeq\mathrm{colim}_n\,I_n$. In particular, if $x\in\pi_0(A)$ is such that the composite $\mathbb{S}\xrightarrow{x} A \to A/I$ is $0$, then $x\colon\mathbb{S}\to A$ factors as $\mathbb{S}\to I \to A$ by the universal property of the fiber. But $\mathbb{S}$ is compact, and therefore there exists an $N$ such that $\mathbb{S}\to I$ factors as $\mathbb{S}\to I_N \to I$. In particular, there exists an $N$ such that the composite $\mathbb{S}\xrightarrow{x} A\to A/I_N$ is already $0$.

Now to the problem at hand. To show that some spectrum $P(n)\otimes x^{-1}R$ is contractible, it suffices to show that the map $x\colon\mathbb{S}\to P(n)\otimes x^{-1}R$ is equivalent to the zero map, because $x$ is also a unit of this spectrum. Since the image of $x$ in $K(\infty)_*R$ is $0$ and $K(\infty)\simeq\mathbb{F}_p\simeq P(\infty)$, we know that $x\colon\mathbb{S}\to P(\infty)\otimes x^{-1}R$ is the zero map. But by definition, $P(\infty)\simeq BP/I'$ where $I':\simeq(p,v_1,v_2,\ldots)$ is an ideal in the sense above. Let $I'_n:\simeq (p,v_1\ldots,v_{n-1})$, and write $I$ and $I_n$ for the corresponding ideals of $A:\simeq BP\otimes x^{-1}R$. Since the tensor product is cocontinuous in each variable, we can write $P(n)\otimes x^{-1}R$ as $A/I_n$ for $1\leq n\leq \infty$ (where $I_\infty:\simeq I$). In the beginning of this paragraph, we have established that $x\colon\mathbb{S}\to A/I$ is the zero map, and by the previous paragraph this implies that there exists a finite $N$ such that $x\colon\mathbb{S}\to A/I_N$ is the zero map as well. As we previously established, this is equivalent to $P(N)\otimes x^{-1}R$ being contractible, and we are done.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! For the first paragraph, you're right, there was $v_n^{-1}$ floating around so much that I mistakenly thought it would be there for $P(n)$. One question about your last paragraph: When you say that $x$ is a unit of the spectrum, do you mean that it is a unit in the homotopy ring? (I would compute that $\pi_{\bullet}(P(n) \otimes x^{-1}R) \cong x^{-1} \pi_{\bullet}(P(n) \otimes R)$ and conclude from here.)

Comment: It is probably cleanest to define $x$ being a unit of some commutative ring spectrum $A$ as meaning that $-\cdot x\colon A\to A$ is an equivalence, and this is how I thought about it in my answer, but this is indeed equivalent to $x$ being a unit in $\pi_0(A)$.